# Geolocation doesn't work with GPS off

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, gps, geolocation

i'm writing a mobile app with htlm5 and javascript using the phonegap build service.
I try to get the geolocation but it doesn't work if the GPS is off on my smartphone. I get the `alert("Sorry, no position available.")` alert after maybe 30 seconds.
If i turned the gps on so i get the geolocation. 
I tried `getCurrentPosition` and `watchPosition` both not work for me.
My Code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var geo_options = {
    enableHighAccuracy : true,
    maximumAge : 30000,
    timeout : 27000
};

function onDeviceReady() {
    // navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error, geo_options);
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success, geo_error, geo_options);
}

function geo_success(position) {
    alert(position.coords.latitude+" "+position.coords.longitude);
}

function geo_error() {
    alert("Sorry, no position available.");
}
```

How can i get the Geolocation when the GPS is Off on the smartphone?

Comment: What is the question? Currently, there are only statements, which are all true.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How can i do it?

Comment: You need to ask the user to enable location services in the UI. You cannot enable it via code.

Comment: You can do a check if(navigator.geolocation) {...} to handle both cases.

Comment: Oh thanks @JamesWaddington. U helped me out. Answer me and i will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check use a check to see if geolocation is available, so that you can handle both cases:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
// get location
} else {
// handle no geolocation
}
```